# use case in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate, 2nd Edition"

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am reading the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate, 2nd Edition". It takes an example of items sold to bidders like ebay. At the page 400, the author says

> The query `select i from item i left join fetch i.bids b where b.amount > 20`  is invalid. You can’t say, “Load the Item instances and initialize their bids collections, but only with Bid instances that have a certain amount.”

I am not sure to quite understand. To my opinion it is valid, but it will renders only the items that have a bid which amount is greater than 20. It will render in that case an inner join with that condition

Furthermore is the following request `select i from item i left join fetch i.bids b on b.amount > 20` valid?

Comment: the example is about HQL (Hibernate's query language) not SQL per se, correct?

Comment: yes it is about HQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select i from item i left join fetch i.bids b where b.amount > 20` as HQL is invalid. Because the HQL results is used to return **Item** objects, you cannot tell hibernate to please create `Item` objects but when you create it, do not populate it with **all** `Bid`s but populate only with `Bid`s with amount greater than 20.

Consider the following class

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    Collection<Bid> bids;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<Bid> getBids() {
        return bids;
    }

    public void setBids(Collection<Bid> bids) {
        this.bids = bids;
    }
}
```

**Update: (Lets run through an example to see what would have happened if hibernate allowed this query)**

**[image: Update: (Lets run through an example if hibernate allowed this query)]**

Major issues if hibernate had allowed it to happen:

1. First issue this will be conceptually wrong because any service using the item1 java object that was returned from the repo does not know item.getBids only contains bid with amount > 20
2. Hibernate only keeps one object reference to represent a database entity in a session (**Repeatable Read guarantee, dirty checking etc**). So if you do another `Select i from Item i where i.itemId = 1` , hibernate has a problem because now it has to have two java objects to represent item 1 in that session (one with bids where the amount > 20 and another with all bids of item1)

Hope this explains clearly why the query can't be allowed