# problems with OneToMany including a filter clause in spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I currently get unexpected results in my MYSQL8/H2 test-case when using on a @OneToMany relationship in spring jpa. I want to filter in a list of TKBColumn-tables inside my TKBData table using JPQL. I expect to get one TKBData-table with the filtered TKBColumn but I always get the TKBData-table with ALL TKBColumn (unfiltered). When I using a SQL command it works!

I got no Idea whats the problem here, why it always give me the TKBData-table with always ALL TKBColumn-tables inside.

Native Query (This works):

```
SELECT d.id,c.name FROM TKBDATA d LEFT JOIN TKBDATA_TKBCOLUMN dc ON d.ID = dc.TKBDATA_ID LEFT JOIN TKBCOLUMN c ON c.ID = dc.COLUMNS_ID WHERE c.name =  'column1';
```

Output

```
ID      NAME  
7b6ec910-3e53-40a3-9221-ee60e75c8d67    column1
```

JPQL Query (Not works):

```
select d from TKBData d LEFT JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = :name
```

Output:

```
id: e892bc28-c35f-4fc8-9b09-387f97a758d8, name:column1
id: 069cc76b-3487-4ad8-a4ae-6568694e2287, name:column2
```

Table 'TKBData'

```
public class TKBData {

    @Id
    @Builder.Default
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<TKBColumn> columns = Sets.newHashSet();
    
    ...
}
```

Table 'TKBColumn'

```
public class TKBColumn {

    @Id
    @Builder.Default
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    
    ...
}
```

Spring Data Repository

```
@Service
public interface KBDataRepository extends CrudRepository<TKBData, String>, KBDataCustomRepository {

    @Query("select d from TKBData d LEFT JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = :name")
    public TKBData filterByColumn(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Spring JPA Generated H2 Tables (relevant)

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."TKBCOLUMN"(
    "ID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(255),
    ...
)
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."TKBDATA_TKBCOLUMN"(
    "TKBDATA_ID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "COLUMNS_ID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."TKBDATA"(
    "ID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

Relevant Content of tables which are generated at the start of the test class

```
Table: TKBDATA

ID
726004cf-5cab-4b1d-bb3f-466ba22622e9


Table: TKBDATA_TKBCOLUMN

TKBDATA_ID                              COLUMNS_ID  
726004cf-5cab-4b1d-bb3f-466ba22622e9    7b4e4ea8-4ff9-4668-8882-67ff93b595ca
726004cf-5cab-4b1d-bb3f-466ba22622e9    d670e813-0466-48a8-be54-ee992cf28462


Table: TKBCOLUMN

ID                                DATAORDER  NAME   OWNERID  
d670e813-0466-48a8-be54-ee992cf28462    0   column1 16e01046-9a84-4651-98d8-4e3e358212eb
7b4e4ea8-4ff9-4668-8882-67ff93b595ca    1   column2 16e01046-9a84-4651-98d8-4e3e358212eb
```

For more informations you can find the github repository here: 
 https://github.com/fo0/ScrumTool

Test class: 
 https://github.com/fo0/ScrumTool/blob/master/ScrumTool/src/test/java/com/fo0/vaadin/scrumtool/test/data/TKBDataColumnFilterTest.java

Edit:
The solution for this was to use a native query, because of the design of JPA and how it works with objects, thats why my use-case has exactly this problem.

Comment: Maybe your relation is many to many you are using a joining table in the native query. And you are not doing any column mapping for one to many also

Comment: the relation should be what it is, a onetomany. The mapping is not directly needed only if you care about performance or "backtrack" objects. This is what I read. But anyway I tried it too with mappings but no effect

Comment: you are welcome if you give me some hints to solve my problem. The question is still why it has (for me incorrect) bahaviour for my JPQL filtering query

Comment: Now I understand you just using auto generated table. You can use @joinColumn to avoid extra joining table

Comment: Meaning the of JPA query is return `TKBDATA` objects where it has at least one associated `TKBCOLUMN` which has the value of `column2`.  For example if you change you test class to `dataRepository.filterByColumn("column3");`, it will not return any objects but whenever it returns a matching `TKBDATA` object, it will return all of its columns

Comment: alright I understand this behaviour now, your example making it more clearly for me, thanks.

Comment: @fo0 how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Meaning of `select d from TKBData d JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = column1`** is

  1. Find a TKBData object where it has an associated `column` object for which `name` is `column1`
  2. Once its decided which TKBData has at least one `column` object for which `name` is `column1`, **then it will return all its associated `column` objects** which you don't have control over in JPA. ( see [My answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473979/use-case-in-the-book-java-persistence-with-hibernate-2nd-edition/62474750#62474750) ). Alternative is to write native sql and return custom non entity objects
  3. For example, you have `TKBDATA_1` with  `column1` and `column2` associated, you also have `TKBDATA_2` with `column3` associated.
  4. When you run your query, it will ignore `TKBDATA_2` and decides to return `TKBDATA_1` as it has atleast one `column` object with `name`= `column2`. **But after that** you don't have control over which associated `column` objects to return for `TKBDATA_1` and JPA will return **all associated column objects**
  5. If you are not sure of the reason, read about hibernate session.How it provides unique presentation of any associated entry in memory. It is the foundation for its `dirty checking` and `repeatable read`
- Update your `@OneToMany` as follows

```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
           cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @Builder.Default
   @JoinTable(name = "TKBDATA_TKBCOLUMN", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TKBDATA_ID"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMNS_ID"))
   private Set<TKBColumn> columns = Sets.newHashSet();
```

- When it comes to JPA query language, I would like to think in terms of query a collection of in-memory objects.
- So now try to describe the meaning of the following two queries in terms of objects.

```
   select d from TKBData d LEFT JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = :name
```

```
           vs
```

```
   select d from TKBData d JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = :name
```

- Don't forget unlike in sql where you are select any columns here you have said you want to select TKBData objects and restricting which TKBData objects to return.
- So to achieve the same result as of your native sql, use the second JPA query

**Note:**

Even though you used a left join in your sql query, it is effectively an inner join sql query because you also applied a  `where` condition to the most right table on that join.

Comment: alright, I am pretty sure that I tested it with mapping too but Im going to add the mapping and check it again, thanks for the hints. Telling you the results later.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai When there is no mapping with Unidirectional `@OneToMany`, a join table was created I don't think there is any problem in mapping, here you will find some good example https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I added your @JoinTable suggestion but it didnt change my result. I still get 2 columns back instead of 1.

Comment: Im just reading the article which you posted, it looks pretty good, thanks. Hope this helps me to solve the problem.

Comment: I read the article, thx!. But anyway whats your suggestion to solve the problem with the goal to get only the filtered result and not the full record? I understand that there would be a problem for JPA to result a filtered tkbdata because of the hashcode etc but the hashcode would change if there are more results in the list and so on ... what I still search is a approach how it would be possible in my use-case to get the filtered tkbdata with the filtered data. IMO its a big problem in JPA not to return this filtered data!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216828/discussion-between-fo0-and-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai).

Answer (score 1):

Use the DISTINCT JPQL keyword

```
@Query("select distinct d from TKBData d LEFT JOIN d.columns c WHERE c.name = :name")
public TKBData filterByColumn(@Param("name") String name);
```

Or use JPA method naming query

```
public TKBData findByColumnsName(String name);
```

Comment: distinct doesn't help here the root of the problem is not about duplicated data. The naming query part is interesing, is this generated by spring?

Comment: Yes, and you have to use distinct when joining and use `List<TKBData>` if there is possibility of multiple result coming

Comment: [Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) you will find different @OneToMany mapping details with example