# How to select all rows in hibernate with extra table with the use of HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

#### Update 2

Query:

```
select distinct p.name, u.cookie_id
    from product p
    left join user_product up on p.id = up.product_id
    left join user u on up.user_id = u.id
    where p.active = true
    and
    (
       u.cookie_id = '4c2fe5b2-73fe-4b28-baa6-23db0512114c'
           or
       not (exists (
         select p1.id
         from user_product up1, product p1
         where p1.id = up1.product_id
       ))
    )
```

Output:
[image]

how should be:
[image]

#### Update 1

I wrote the code with the use of `stream()` for the better understanding of the problem:

```
        List<Product> productList = productRepository.findAllByActiveTrue();
        productList = productList.stream().map(item -> {
            if(item.getUserProducts() == null) return item;

            List<UserProduct> userProductList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (UserProduct userProduct : item.getUserProducts()) {
                if(userProduct.getUser().getCookieId().equals(cookieId)){
                    userProductList.add(userProduct);
                }
            }
            item.setUserProducts(userProductList);
            return item;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to know how correctly select data from the tables. I want to get **all** products.

But to get all products is easy. I also need to include in the output data (UserProducts and User) if there's a connection between Product and User by CookieId. In other words, I want to show all products with User and UserProducts (if possible) and exclude the relation Product-UserProduct-User if User's cookieId doesn't match the cookieId from the query.

I am trying the following query, but it returns me only products that has the connection between User and the product, not all products.

```
@Query("from Product pr join fetch pr.userProducts up left join fetch up.user u where pr.active = true and u.cookieId = :cookieId")
    List<Product> getAllProductsByCookieId(UUID cookieId);
```

My database looks like this:
[image: Database]

Visualisation of the idea:
[image]

SQL-queries to  generate tables:

product-table

```
create table if not exists product
(
    id bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    active bit not null,
    image_path varchar(255) null,
    name varchar(255) null,
    price double not null,
    unit_number double null,
    unit_type varchar(255) null
);
```

userProduct-table

```
create table if not exists user_product
(
    quantity int null,
    product_id bigint not null,
    user_id bigint not null,
    primary key (product_id, user_id),
    constraint FKnw43wab2rt35jmofmpbhkibco
        foreign key (product_id) references product (id),
    constraint FKq5o2e33vlwpfc2k1mredtia6p
        foreign key (user_id) references user (id)
);
```

user-table

```
create table if not exists user
(
    id bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    cookie_id varchar(255) null
);
```

Comment: Do you mean 'all' active? not all? And what does 123 represent cookie id or user id?

Comment: @JGFMK all active products and 123 - cookieId

Comment: If I am not mistaken this would work with raw SQL: `select p.product name, u.cookie_id from product p
left join user_product up on p.id = up.product_id left join user u on up.user_id = user.id where p.active = true and u.cookie_id = '?1?`
Then look here to see if any of it  can be applied to generate the same output:
http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/JPA/Join/Left-join.htm

Comment: @JGFMK That wouldn't work. It will return 2 rows (`onion`, `carrot`), instead of all 4 rows. If I will put in `u.cookie_id = ?1` `null`, it should return all data, but without relations Product-UserProduct-User.

Comment: left join always returns all from your primary table. So I believe it would. You are confusing that with a full join

Comment: At the SQL level, you can  also always break a query down into Common Table Expressions (CTE) using `with`, and use things like Union all if you want to look at subsets of the combined result at a more granular level as well.

Comment: @JGFMK Literally just reading about it)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your requirement is not possible without scaler objects in JPA. i.e JPA cannot give you a `Product` object where `p.getUserProducts()` contains only some `UserProducts`.

   - See my answer here. [Why left join on CriteriaQuery doesn't filter results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659001/why-left-join-on-criteriaquery-doesnt-filter-results/62660891#62660891)
   - or here [problems with OneToMany including a filter clause in spring jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610521/problems-with-onetomany-including-a-filter-clause-in-spring-jpa/62611145#62611145)
2. You have to use the native query option or any other option where you retrieve the columns and provide a mapper as to how to create the object. You can use the following sql query.

```
    select p.product, u.cookie_id 
    from product p 
    left join user_product up on p.id = up.product_id 
    left join user u on up.user_id = u.id and u.cookie_id = '?1'
    where p.active = true
    group by p.product, u.cookie_id
```

Comment: I will have a look now. Sorry for not responding

Comment: I updated my question with the output. Furthermore, I added `create`-query to test data

Comment: It  wouldn't) This query was provided in the comments above

Comment: My bad. I tested the query. It's ALMOST works!!!!!!! Just one thing needs to be done... distinct doesn't work properly. The duplicates appear.

Comment: Try the updated answer with GROUP BY  clause instead of DISTINCT

Comment: Sorry to force you to constantly change your SQL query. I'll check it now! And thank you very much and help!